# Is it a best practice to have both Bind and DNSMasq which is running on port 53?

Tags: dnsmasq, bind9

I installed Bind on CentOS7 and noticed that the DNSMasq which is already installed & running on the same port 53 where Bind runs. Looks like DNSMasq is default package comes up with CentOS.

Command - netstat -lnp|grep 53

I've few queries running in my mind -

1. Is it a good idea to keep both packages which runs on same port 53, will it cause any issue?
2. Is it ok to disable DNSMasq? if so, will it impact other functionlity? and how to permanently remove/disable DNSMasq?

Please can anyone provide some information on these tools, please

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Only one service will be able to bind to port 53 at a time (on the same IP address)

You should disable/uninstall `DNSMasq` if you want to run `bind`.

You `/etc/resolv.conf` is probably set to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, you will need to change this to point at an actual nameserver, or if you have `bind` configured to forward DNS queries then you can set `/etc/resov.conf` to the address `bind` is listening on.

Comment: Removing DNSMasq will result in removing a few other features. Disabling it should be enough.